# React adding component using stateless functions

Tags: reactjs

How can I  make the button to add a new `<Card>` component to the `<Page>`, using only stateless function components?

```
const Card = (props) => <div className="card"><p>{props.bodytext}</p></div>

const AddButton = (props)=>{
  const addCard = (e) => {
    // Add a new <Card /> to <Page />
  }

  return <button onClick={addCard}>+</button>
}


const Page = (props) => (
  <div className="container" id="page">
    <div className="panel"><AddButton/></div>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Page title="Our cards" />,
  document.getElementById('react-container')
);
```

Comment: you need some kind of incremental state to track how many cards you have. then just `.map` then in a container

Comment: why `using only stateless function components` ? What you are describing is adding a state to `Page` component. Can you describe your motivation/constraint? perhaps we can suggest something that suits your needs better